# Make a prediction in Tensorflow C using c_api.h

Tags: c, tensorflow

I want to use tensorflow C api but there is only one [example code](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/lang_c#build). And in that example code there is no explanation on how to open a model graph (saved as a .pb file) using this library and how to make a prediction. (c_api.h code can be found [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/c/c_api.h)). So can someone provide an **example code on how to do something similiar in C using c_api.h**, like in python we can just do something like `model = load_model("filepath")`
and then run `model.predict([input])`

Comment: There is example code on GitHub and questions on Stackoverflow etc if you do a bit of [googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=tensorflow+c+api+example+code+pb+file).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [@WeatherVane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4142924/weather-vane) I found [this](https://github.com/AmirulOm/tensorflow_capi_sample) github repository explaining on how to run python Tensorflow model in C.